# Calling the default exceptionHandler equivalent in SilverStripe 4

Tags: silverstripe-4

I've searched through the documentation and the API for SilverStripe 4 but I'm having trouble using the appropriate class to call the default exception handler.

How it worked before SilverStripe 4 within my Page.php controller's init()

```
    parent::init();

    set_exception_handler(function($exception) {
        if( get_class($exception) == 'CustomException' ) {
            Controller::curr()->handleCustomException($exception);
        }
        return exceptionHandler($exception);
    });
```

How I expect it to work with SilverStripe 4

```
    parent::init();

    set_exception_handler(function($exception) {
        if( get_class($exception) == 'CustomException' ) {
            Controller::curr()->handleCustomException($exception);
        }
        return <SomeMonologClass>::handleException($exception);
    });
```

I'm aware of SilverStripe 4 now using Monolog and I've come across the `handleException` function which I believe is what I need to call instead of `exceptionHandler($exception)`.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use SilverStripe\Control\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    private static $dependencies = [
        'logger' => '%$Psr\Log\LoggerInterface',
    ];

    // This will be set automatically, as long as MyController is instantiated via Injector
    public $logger;

    protected function init()
    {
        $this->logger->debug("MyController::init() called");
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

As described here:

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/debugging/error_handling/#accessing-the-logger-via-dependency-injection

And even more info here: https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/advanced-environment-configuration-1

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been able to fully replicate the default exception handling behaviour but this has me on the right track now.